# Why is no ProgId generated for these ATL Simple Objects?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, com, idl, progid, coclass

I have an ATL DLL with a bunch of ATL Simple Objects (= COM objects), all wizard-generated.

The IDL file contains lots of interfaces and a library section such as this:

```
[
    object,
    uuid(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000),
    dual,
    nonextensible,
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IFoo : IDispatch{
    [id(1)] HRESULT FooMethod();
};
[
    uuid(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000),
    version(1.0),
]
library MyLib
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");
    [
        uuid(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)
    ]
    coclass Foo
    {
        [default] interface IFoo;
    };
}
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24z8966k.aspx) seems to say that a `progid` attribute should be automatically generated for each coclass. However, there are none in my registry. The DLL is otherwise completely normally registered at each compilation and can be used from COM clients without any issues.

How can it happen that the `progid`s are not automatically generated?

Comment: It is a trap in the ATL Simple Object wizard.  You type the "short name" and all of the fields are automatically filled in, nobody minds the defaults.  Except one, buried in the lower right corner.  Yup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I mistook the documentation and for IDL coclasses the ProgID is not automatically generated. Too bad.

Anyway, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725424/atl-com-class-registration-rgs-file-defaults) is explained how to add them to the .rgs files later.